# Typing TypeScript function with custom type to restrict the resulting values

Tags: typescript

I would like to restrict during development time the resulting of the following function using custom Head type.

I have the following custom Head type:

```
type Head<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer First, ...any[]] ? First : never;
```

it works fine with the following example:

```
const headOfArray: Head<[1,2,3]> = 1 // if you try to assign 2 or 3, you will get an error
```

And the following function:

```
function head(arr: unknown[]) {
  const [first, ...rest] = arr;
  return first;
}
```

Is it possible to restrict the return of the `head()` function during the typing of that, using any custom type like the previous one?

Comment: Would this work for your use case? https://tsplay.dev/Nn5Kdw

Comment: If you really want to use your custom type then you can assert it via `return first as Head<T>` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvzKrW).  But I don't understand the use case; do you really want to use a particular custom type, or just get a well-typed return type for your `head` implementation?  Because if it's the latter, then I'd recommend the version in the bottom of that link instead.  And the use cases matter here; if `arr` is of type `number[]`, do you want `head(a)` to be `number` even though `arr` might be empty?  Please [edit] to add clarity.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick reply, I really want to get the first element independently of the type. Then if the first element doesn't match with the expected value based on the custom type, it should be marked with the expected underline error not matching with the expected literal.

Comment: Your custom type is a generic conditional type and the compiler cannot reason well about such things, so the expected error will either not occur or you will get an error when you don’t want one.  Why do you care about this particular custom type?